# App not installed. This app isn't compatible with your phone

Tags: twrp, 7.0-nougat, magisk, systemless-root

Rooted my `Tecno Spark K7` `Android 7.0 Nougat` (Stock ROM + Magisk + TWRP). Trying to reinstall my apps from backup apks but I'm getting this message `App not installed. This app isn't compatible with your phone.` Doesn't really make sense to me, since I'm using the same apks that were installed on the same phone with the same stock ROM.

Only difference is the rooting but my old phone was also rooted, and I had no trouble reinstalling its apps, so I honestly don't see how rooting is the cause of my current issue.
How do I solve this?

Comment: install from Google Play, or copy files into /data/app/<pkgname>-1/base.apk and chown 1000.1000

Comment: @alecxs, I'm going to try that and see how it goes. Thanks.